# Simple replace dot by comma after fpeval

Tags: macros

I want to simply replace the dot of the fpeval result with comma. Very simple, no additional features, so siunitx and numprint etc. is not working because they are modifying and adding to much stuff. The following code should work without warnings:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{1.2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{3.4}
    \begin{Form}
%       \TextField[value=\replaceDotWithComma{\fpeval{\x+\y}}]{\replaceDotWithComma{\fpeval{\x+\y}}}
        \TextField[value=\fpeval{\x+\y}]{\fpeval{\x+\y}}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \mich_convert_tocomma:n #1
  {
    \exp_args:Ne \tl_to_str:n
      { \str_map_function:nN {#1} \__mich_convert_tocomma:n }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__mich_convert_tocomma:n #1
      {
        \int_compare:nNnTF { `#1 } = { `. }
          { , }
          { #1 }
      }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn  \mich_convert_tocomma:n {e}
\cs_set_eq:NN \tocomma \mich_convert_tocomma:e
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{1.2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{3.4}
    \begin{Form}
%       \TextField[value=\replaceDotWithComma{\fpeval{\x+\y}}]{\replaceDotWithComma{\fpeval{\x+\y}}}
        \TextField[value=\tocomma{\fpeval{\x+\y}}]{\tocomma{\fpeval{\x+\y}}}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the internal printing function but this will surely bring other problems with it.  In particular this is not future-proof, since any name starting with double underscore (`__`) may change or disappear without notice at any point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set:Npn \__fp_to_decimal_large:Nnnw #1#2#3#4;
  {
    \exp_after:wN \__fp_trim_zeros:w \int_value:w
      \if_int_compare:w #2 > 0 \exp_stop_f:
        #2
      \fi:
      \exp_stop_f:
      #3{,}#4 ;
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\fpeval{1.2 + 3.4}

\end{document}
```